# Custom page Error 500 in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I added the following in my web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On"  defaultRedirect="~/Error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Error404" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/Error500" />
  </customErrors>
```

And my ErrorController:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Error404()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Error500()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

I Have the views `Error404` and `Error500`.

The Error 404 works as excpected but not the Error 500.

The action `Error500()` is not called and what is rendered is a view called `Error.cshtml` that is inside de shared folder of the views folder.

I don't understand why action `Error500()` isn't called.

I have ELMAH installed. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Perhaps error 500 was not raised at all ? From the specs: "500 Internal Server Error - The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request. "

Comment: @Veverke I added this line of code in my action to raise an error: `int u = Convert.ToInt32("");// Error line` And I see that the browser receives a page with error code 500

Comment: I did the same as you, and the same happens. Haven't figured out a solution yet (I was myself searching the web for how to implement custom error pages today).

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work, but try setting the defaultRedirect element equal to your "~/Error/Error500".

> defaultRedirect   Specifies the default URL to direct a browser to if an
>   error occurs. When defaultRedirect is not specified, a generic error
>   is displayed instead. The URL may be absolute (for instance,
>   http://www.contoso.com/ErrorPage.htm) or it may be relative. A
>   relative URL such as /ErrorPage.htm is relative to the Web.config file
>   that specified the defaultRedirect URL, not to the Web page in which
>   the error occurred. A URL starting with a tilde (~),such as
>   ~/ErrorPage.htm, means that the specified URL is relative to the root
>   path of the application.

Comment: That is really weird. The 500 error method should definitely be called. Even without the default redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I also have Elmah installed and tried your example and go the same result - error 404 works but error 500 doesn't.

Could it be that you are getting your error 500 when making a Ajax call? 
If so I got solved this by adding a statusCode attribute like so.

```
 $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCatalogue")',
            data: dropDownSelected,
            success: function (data) {
                location.href = '@Url.Action("GetPdfFile")/?fileNameGuid=' + encodeURIComponent(data); // download the actual file

            },
            statusCode: {
                500: function () {
                    kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), false);
                    location.href = '@Url.Action("Error500", "Error")';
                }
            }
        });
```